# can't read ftp2 no such variable

Tags: ns2

i run ns2 code but it is throwing a warning with error

warning: no class variable LanRouter::debug_

```
    see tcl-object.tcl in tclcl for info about this warning.
```

can't read "ftp2": no such variable
while executing
"list $ftp2 start"
invoked from within
"$ns at 1.0 [list $ftp2 start]"
(file "sai3.tcl" line 50)

My ns2 program is
lab3.tcl

```
'set ns [new Simulator]
set nf [open lab3.nam w]
$ns namtrace-all $nf
set nd [open lab3.tr w]
$ns trace-all $nd
$ns color 1 Blue
$ns color 2 Red
proc finish { } {
global ns nf nd
$ns flush-trace
close $nf
close $nd
exec nam lab3.nam &
exit 0
}
set n0 [$ns node]
set n1 [$ns node]
set n2 [$ns node]
set n3 [$ns node]
set n4 [$ns node]
set n5 [$ns node]
set n6 [$ns node]
set n7 [$ns node]
set n8 [$ns node]
$n7 shape box
$n7 color Blue
$n8 shape hexagon
$n8 color Red
$ns duplex-link $n1 $n0 2Mb 10ms DropTail
$ns duplex-link $n2 $n0 2Mb 10ms DropTail
$ns duplex-link $n0 $n3 1Mb 20ms DropTail
$ns make-lan "$n3 $n4 $n5 $n6 $n7 $n8" 512Kb 40ms LL Queue/DropTail Mac/802_3
$ns duplex-link-op $n1 $n0 orient right-down
$ns duplex-link-op $n2 $n0 orient right-up
$ns duplex-link-op $n0 $n3 orient right
$ns queue-limit $n0 $n3 20
set tcp1 [new Agent/TCP/Vegas]
$ns attach-agent $n1 $tcp1
set sink1 [new Agent/TCPSink]
$ns attach-agent $n7 $sink1
$ns connect $tcp1 $sink1
$tcp1 set class_ 1
$tcp1 set packetSize_ 55
set ftp1 [new Application/FTP]
$ftp1 attach-agent $tcp1
set tfile [open cwnd.tr w]
$tcp1 attach $tfile
$tcp1 trace cwnd_
$ns at 0.5 "$ftp1 start"
$ns at 1.0 "$ftp2 start"
$ns at 5.0 "$ftp2 stop"
$ns at 5.0 "$ftp1 stop"
$ns at 5.5 "finish"
$ns run'
```

Comment: I do not know anything about `ns2`, but where is `$ftp2` defined?  From where does it get a value ?

Comment: Missing "ftp2 definition". Example ftp2 settings, `2-lab3.tcl` etc. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1QLMVw5lbzZrjoid817G5oR29YIkMdysb?usp=sharing .......... All 3000 ex https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B7S255p3kFXNSmRYb2lGcDRUdWs?resourcekey=0-vrEMHtGTFP3yLoTQz_UAwA&usp=sharing